# Ajustar tamanho da DIV ao conteúdo

Tags: css

Estou trabalhando em um chat para um site, o chat está Ok, mas como sempre apanho para configurar o CSS.

Quero ajustar a DIV ao tamanho do conteúdo e colocar, só que a DIV ocupa 100% da largura.

```
.div-chat-i {
color:#000000;
background-color:#C6E2FF;
padding:5px 12px;
border-radius:10px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
width: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div é um elemento do tipo bloco, e por default ocupa 100% da largura da tela, ou do elemento do qual estiver dentro.

Veja no exemplo abaixo que eu coloquei ela com 15% da largura do pai, que no caso é o body, que por default tem 100% da largura da tela...

**EDIT:** No exemplo que fiz, deixe a div, com largura mínima de 15% e máxima de 25%, então se o conteúdo for pequeno ocupa no mínimo 15%, e se form maior que 25% a linha vai quebrar.

OBS: usei `position:absolut` para posicionar o chat no canto inferior direito

```css
.div-chat-i {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#C6E2FF;
    padding:5px 12px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    /* estilo de posicionamento e largura*/
    min-width: 15%; 
    max-width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-chat-i">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam asperiores ratione adipisci dolorem animi ut.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Value Hugo, ajustei tamanhos para não coupar 100%